# postgresql convert 'Thu Jul 02 13:36:17 UTC 2020' to timestamp

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp

I have a string that I need to insert into a table as a timestamp.
'Thu Jul 02 13:36:17 UTC 2020'
Without UTC the following conversion works
SELECT to_timestamp('Thu Jul 02 13:36:17 2020', 'Dy Mon dd HH24:MI:SS yyyy');
How can I convert the timestamp with the UTC portion?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Database Type: PostgreSQL
Table Data Type: timestamp (this can change if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always going to be `UTC`, then you can use:

```
> select to_timestamp(
      'Thu Jul 02 13:36:17 UTC 2020',
      'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS UTC YYYY'
);
```